# Blogger API, OAuth 2.0

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, google-api, blogger

I'm trying to automate OAuth 2.0 from the blogger APIs, but I'm not finding it, my code keeps giving an error because there is something unauthorized related to OAuth 2.0, what do I need to release to be able to continue with my code?

I'm trying to create a post automation code, and I use the blogger APIs as a photo directory, but my results are not interesting, due to OAuth 2.0